# Facebook Messenger :How to show a greeting message when start conversation

Tags: node.js, facebook, messenger, facebook-messenger

I want to show a greeting message when start a conversation on Facebook Messenger ( before any user input ) . How to do it? 
The problem is : My code is for server by NodeJS ,and it only trigger when a message is send to server ,which mean it only be triggered when users send something.
Facebook messenger doesn't send anything when you press button "Message".
I have check this link Messenger Greeting , but it only shows when a new user starts chat ,but i need show it when starting conversations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set a welcome message, using the Facebook Api.
Find the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/implementation#welcome_screen

As explained in the documentation, you have to make a POST request to `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<PAGE_ID>/thread_settings?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>`

You need to make the POST request only once, then Facebook will automatically prompt your welcome message whenever a user starts a chat.

Comment: The Welcome Screen only appears for new conversations. On mobile, deleting conversations will not cause the Welcome Screen to appear again. On desktop web, if you delete the conversation, you can make the Welcome Screen appear again

Comment: Welcome Screen should appear on both mobile and desktop web when we delete conversations and start new one.??Can be other ways ??

Answer (score 2):

I wrote and answer for this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960857/how-to-show-personalized-welcome-message-in-facebook-messenger?answertab=active#tab-top).

Have a nice working ;)