# How to show personalized 'Welcome Message' in facebook messenger?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I would like to show 'welcome message' like 'Hi Robert, welcome to my application'.
So I need to send:

1. "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/USER_ID?fields=first_name,last_name,profile_pic,locale,timezone,gender&access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
2. using 'first_name' from 1st request, send "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/PAGE_ID/thread_settings?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN" request to set 'welcome message'.

However, I need to know user_id before first request.

My questions:

1. What are steps to create 'Welcome message'?
2. How to show 'Welcome message', when user opened facebook messenger window?

I reviewed https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform document, and I have still questions.

Answer (score 6):

So you can make this with a ["get started"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/get-started-button) Button. This button is only there if the User Messages the bot for the first time.

With this command you can set the button:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type":"call_to_actions",
  "thread_state":"new_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
      "payload":"USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
    }
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

As you can see if the Button is pressed your Webhook recieves a "postback"

this is the callback you get:

```
{
  "sender":{
    "id":"USER_ID"
  },
  "recipient":{
    "id":"PAGE_ID"
  },
  "timestamp":1458692752478,
  "postback":{
    "payload":"USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
  }
}
```

So this is from where you can get User id

Now you can code a Function for this.
My looks like this:

```
function receivedPostback(event) {
  var senderID = event.sender.id;
  var recipientID = event.recipient.id;
  var timeOfPostback = event.timestamp;

  // The 'payload' param is a developer-defined field which is set in a postback 
  // button for Structured Messages. 
  var payload = event.postback.payload;

  console.log("Received postback for user %d and page %d with payload '%s' " + 
    "at %d", senderID, recipientID, payload, timeOfPostback);


  if (payload) {

    // When a postback is called, we'll send a message back to the sender to 
    // let them know it was successful
      switch (payload) {
        case 'USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD':
          startedConv(senderID);
          break;

       default:
         sendTextMessage(senderID, "Postback called");
       }
```

My *startedConv()* looks like this

```
function startedConv(recipientId){
var name;

request({
          url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/'+ recipientId +'?fields=first_name',
          qs: {access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN},
          method: 'GET'
      }, function(error, response, body) {
          if (error) {
              console.log('Error sending message: ', error);
          } else if (response.body.error) {
              console.log('Error: ', response.body.error);
          }else{
              name = JSON.parse(body);
              sendTextMessage(recipientId, "Hello "+ name.first_name+", how can i help you ? ")
          }
      });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need it. Just follow the steps below,

1- Go to your page that related your messenger api.

2- Settings (FB Page Settings)

3- From tabs select Messaging

4- In messaging tab at the bottom you will see "Show a Messenger Greeting" change it from "No" to "Yes". Than you can customize it ;)

**Note: To see your greeting message you should delete your previous conversation with the page that you set greeting message. Then start new conversation with the page you should see greeting message.**

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have tried this option as well. But it did not work for me. I put my message and set 'Yes' to show and click 'Save button'. Unfortunately it did not work (. Maybe I missed some settings?

Comment: Is your app approved ? If No for now only admin, testers, and developers can see that message. And for you can check it like that, Add a friend to your test group in messenger app settings. Message should appear after he open converisation window.

Comment: Step 1 of your instructions is totally unclear as for what you mean. I searched all pages in the App Dashboard in developers.facebook... and I found no setting for a Greeting :(

Comment: For example my page name is : KayzerSoze-1795503650697564
And settings url :
 https://www.facebook.com/KayzerSoze-1795503650697564/settings/?tab=messaging 
Just change "KayzerSoze-1795503650697564" with your page username.

Comment: @iBobb It's not in the App Dashboard, it's in the FB Page Settings

Comment: @Omera This doesn't work well, I've turned on and off, customized, it doesn't change the Welcome Greetings. I think this is a bug that Facebook have not fixed until now.

Comment: @Carmela I just tried and it shows me greeting message. Can you try to delete conversation i mean conversation which is you made with your page and start new one then check the greetings ?

Comment: @Omera I already did that, several times. Didn't work. I even disabled the greeting message through the FB Page, still didn't work.

Comment: @Carmela Are you trying too see from Mobile Messenger Application right ? Because i don't see greetings in desktop i mean in https://www.messenger.com/. Only in my mobile phone's messenger apps.

Comment: @Omera Yes, that's right. My other FB Page responds to the changing greeting text, the other does not. I am admin to both pages. I explained the bug here:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/135976446978726/

Answer (score 1):

As of 9/12 you can set the greeting text that shows up before your user hits Get Started and it includes these tokens that will be replaced when the text is rendering:

- {{user_first_name}}
- {{user_last_name}}
- {{user_full_name}}

Take a look at this page of the Messenger Platform docs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/greeting-text

Answer (score 1):

Creating a Greeting Text isn't hard at all at this point. I spent some time finding out how to do it and it turned out quite simple. I refactored one of the methods for a `POST` request that I found in the samples and I'm using **NodeJS** btw.

```
function createGreetingApi(data) {
request({
uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings',
qs: { access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
method: 'POST',
json: data

}, function (error, response, body) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
  console.log("Greeting set successfully!");
} else {
  console.error("Failed calling Thread Reference API", response.statusCode,     response.statusMessage, body.error);
}
});  
}
```

Then I have another method just so that I keep code readable:

```
function setGreetingText() {
var greetingData = {
setting_type: "greeting",
greeting:{
text:"Hi {{user_first_name}}, welcome!"
}
};
createGreetingApi(greetingData);
}
```

Then you use this method in `app.listen` like this:

```
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
setGreetingText();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So i guess in messenger this happens for the very first message. If you delete message and start over this is NOT triggered. In Facebook messages you see it working.